# Dependency Check report from Jenkins does not show on SonarQube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I've been facing with a problem when pushing the report from jenkins job to sonarqube. 
**I do not see the vulnerabilities found on SonarQube only the html report.**

Jenkins.

[image]
[image]
Files generated:
[image]
SonarQube
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently not working with 6.7.2 sonarqube , had to downgrade to 1.10 sq dependency check version and it works. (issue posted on their git also)